# How to controll some actions or state outside when using react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

If I navigate A screen to B screen by `react-navigation`.

It will generate a `Header` automatically.

So if I want to add some button deal with like control state or call api on the `Header`.

I have to add `static navigationOptions` like this

```
class B extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `${navigation.state.params.barTitle}`,
    headerBackTitle: null,
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerRight:
    <TouchableOpacity 
      style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingRight: 20 }}
      onPress={() => {
        callApi();
      }} 
    >
      <Text>Call API</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  });

  // other code...
}
```

But it declare `static navigationOptions` under class B.

If I set all of my `react-navigation` settings on another folder:

navigator/index.js

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

import RootScreen from '../screens/RootScreen';
import LoginStack from './LoginStack';
import MainStack from './MainStack';

const RootStack = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    RootScreen: RootScreen,
    LoginStack: LoginStack,
    MainStack: MainStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'RootScreen',
  }
)


const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default AppContainer;
```

navigator/LoginStack.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen';
import A from '../screens/A';
import B from '../screens/B';

const LoginStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen },
    A: { screen: A },
    B: { screen: B }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'LoginScreen',
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
);

export default LoginStack;
```

I can't figure it out, how do I achieve that control the state or call api actions on `LoginStack.js` file ?

Do not consider customization my `Header`. If I want to use `react-navigation` `Header`. Is the only way I have to declare `static navigationOptions` under class B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough.

From which file you are trying to call API in LoginStack.js?
By control state, you mean Navigation State or Component State?

What I have understood is you want to call API in each route Screen as API is in the parent file.

You can pass screenProps to call api as shown below.(You can edit the render method to add custom Header)

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

// Login Stack
import ScreenA from './ScreenA';
import ScreenB from './ScreenB';

const LoginStackRoute = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ScreenA: ScreenA,
    ScreenB: ScreenB
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'ScreenA',
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
);

var LoginStackContainer = createAppContainer(LoginStackRoute);

export default class LoginStack extends React.Component{
  alertTest(){
    alert('hi')
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <>
        <View style={{height:50,width:'100%', backgroundColor:'red'}}>
          <Text>Custom Header</Text>
        </View>
        <LoginStackContainer screenProps={{alertTest: ()=>this.alertTest()}}/>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

ScreenA or ScreenB can access the API in route file as

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';


export default class ScreenA extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>This is Screen A</Text>
        <Button 
          title='alert'
          onPress={()=>{this.props.screenProps.alertTest()}}
        ></Button>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Learned it !